# How get decimal values?

Tags: help, math

windows 10, emacs 26.1

Open `*scratch*` buffer and do next:

`(/ 15 6)` press `C-x C-e`

Result is in minibuffer:

```
2 (#o2, #x2, ?\C-b)
```

As you can see the result is INTEGER value. But I need correct value = **2.5**

How I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're happy with floating point arithmetic then you just need to make one of the numbers a float.  e.g.:

```
(/ 15.0 6)
=> 2.5
```

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Arithmetic Operations`

> each of these functions accepts both integer and
>   floating-point arguments, and returns a floating-point number if any
>   argument is floating point.